# REGEX statement to pull out digits after a variable string

Tags: regex

I am trying to pull out a few digits that occur within a complex string, based on the identifier "**bas**". As an example, if I have a string: "went ahead 5m, backed @45 degrees, **bas = 30**", I want to pull out the digits "**30**." Doing this for the above string is simple, but the syntax of the string is rarely regular, which is what I can't figure out how to deal with: the location of "bas + digits" within the string varies (front, middle, end), the digits may come before "bas" (such as "30 = bas"), and/or there may be something else between the digits and bas, such as "bas: 30" or "30-bas" or even "30-40 bas".

Here is the code I have written that does a good job pulling out the digits from one specific string format:

```
import re
p="went ahead 5m, backed @45 degrees, bas = 30"
c = re.search('bas = (\d{,5})', p, re.IGNORECASE)
print(c.group(1))
```

> result: 30

The issue is I have several thousand rows of data that I want to search through and pull out the bas-associated digits, and the formatting of the strings varies as described above. Any ideas on how to deal with this so I can implement a code that successfully deals with varying string formats?

Comment: I see that there are no word characters between the `bas` and the number. Does `(\d+(?:-\d+)?)\W*bas\b|\bbas\W*(\d+(?:-\d+)?)` capture the right values for you? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZC1BO/1). See this [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZZCJfw).

Answer (score 0):

As there are no word characters between the `bas` word and the number, I suggest using

```py
(\d+(?:-\d+)?)\W*bas\b|\bbas\W*(\d+(?:-\d+)?)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZC1BO/2). Note: there are two alternatives in this pattern, and either the first or the second capturing group matches, so either one will always contain some value.

*Details*

- `(\d+(?:-\d+)?)\W*bas\b` - one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `-` and one or more digits (captured into Group 1) and then zero or more non-word chars and a whole word `bas`
- `|` - or
- `\bbas\W*(\d+(?:-\d+)?)` - a whole word `bas`, then zero or more non-word chars and then one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `-` and one or more digits (captured into Group 2).

See this [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZZCJfw):

```py
import re
pattern = r"(\d+(?:-\d+)?)\W*bas\b|\bbas\W*(\d+(?:-\d+)?)"
texts = ["went ahead 5m, backed @45 degrees, bas = 30", "30 = bas", "bas: 30", "30-bas", "30-40 bas"]
for text in texts:
    m = re.search(pattern, text, re.I)
    if m:
        print(text, [x for x in m.groups() if x][0], sep=" :=>: " )
```

Output:

```
went ahead 5m, backed @45 degrees, bas = 30 :=>: 30
30 = bas :=>: 30
bas: 30 :=>: 30
30-bas :=>: 30
30-40 bas :=>: 30-40
```